# how to indicate a point(as per coordinaates) on map(output)

Tags: matlab

I have a map of an area as a output of my matlab code indicating latitude and longitude as axis(not 2D but with projection). I want to show a point along with circle surrounding the point on output map. I will give coordinates as my input in my code and get point(as per coordinates) surrounded by circle as output. The basic concept of my code is below..TR3 is my input variable...

Suppose I want to show 50N,70E on map. Can anyone suggest me how to do this??

```
Z = russia.map;    
[phi lambda] = meshgrid (Longitude, Latitude);    
b1 = phi > 50;
b2 = phi < 150;    
b = b1 & b2;    
d1 = lambda > 40;    
d2 = lambda <= 80;
d = d1 & d2;   
C = b & d;    
TR4 = TR3(C)*10000;    
Tr4 = cat(1,TR4,zeros(40,1));
TR5 = reshape(Tr4,40,100);    
R = georasterref('RasterSize', size(Z), ...
    'latlim',[40 80], 'lonlim',[50 150]);
worldmap(Z,R)
surfm(lat_new,long_new,TR5)
```

Comment: Not sure whether this solves it, but if you know how to plot the map and how to plot the point: put a `hold on` in between and you can plot one on top of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plotting stuff into your projection use "plotm".

```
........
worldmap(Z,R);
hold on; 
surfm(lat_new,long_new,TR5);
plotm(50, 70, 'x');
........ 
hold off;
```

Reference: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/map/create-a-world-map.html